Where can I find an up-to-date checklist for HIPAA compliance (extra points for newbie friendly ones)?
I'm not happy with the HIPAA checklists I've found online, I'm looking for something clearer and more comprehensive for beginners.
I've downloaded probably 7 or 8 free HIPAA checklists from HIPAA related sites, but I've yet to find one that isn't overly concise or straightup vague.
I'm looking for something that will link me to further resources, while really outlining the path that a HIPAA data compliance specialist or security officer needs to take from A to Z.
Bonus if it's something I can share with the compliance team and other staff, and something that can be revisited as a reference.

You've found 7 or 8 checklists but none of them meet your needs? That seems like a lot. Since you don't list what you found, it's likely that anything we point you to is something you've already found.

Hi Carey, all of the checklists I've found are one or two pages max and really not very useful for beginners or people wanting something a bit more comprehensive. As mentioned, I need something with A to Z steps that links to further reading where necessary. The idea is that I have staff who're not comfortable with the complex HIPAA language, so they need it clarified in simple terms.

I don't know why you think that "outlining the path that a HIPAA data compliance specialist or security officer needs to take from A to Z" should be as simple as a checklist - that's a person's entire job.

I agree with @BryanKrause. Complying with HIPAA is fairly simple and intuitive for medical providers, but designing and managing data compliance is a very different matter. If I were starting a company that handled data subject to HIPAA, I would hire an employee or consultant with expertise in the subject. The cost of failure can be very high.

Here are a few suggestions I think might help:

HHS.gov Official Resources

The U.S. Department of Health and Human Services offers detailed HIPAA compliance tools, tailored for both beginners and experts. Their resources include practical guidance on security, privacy, and breach notification rules.
Link: HHS HIPAA Compliance Tools


Compliancy Group’s Roadmap

This program breaks down HIPAA compliance into actionable steps with a visual roadmap that’s easy for non-technical teams to follow.
It’s great for sharing across teams and includes tools for tracking compliance progress.
Link: Compliancy Group


NIST HIPAA Security Toolkit

NIST offers an in-depth toolkit to help align your practice with the HIPAA Security Rule. While more technical, it’s invaluable for compliance officers and IT teams.
Link: NIST HIPAA Toolkit


Infosec Institute

They provide beginner-friendly HIPAA guides with training resources for your compliance team. It’s a practical way to educate staff unfamiliar with complex HIPAA language.
Link: Infosec HIPAA Guide


Create a Custom Binder for Your Team

If nothing you find meets your needs exactly, consider combining these resources into a centralized, easy-to-navigate binder or digital repository. Include:

An overview of HIPAA fundamentals.
A step-by-step compliance checklist.
Links to further reading and training materials.


This way, you’ll have a dynamic resource you can update and revisit over time.



I hope this helps!
